# F# 3.0 compiler error FS0193 when upgrading project

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm getting a strange `FSharp.Core`-related error when building one of my larger projects, and the error doesn't contain any location information to help me track down where the problem is.

The compile error is `error FS0193: The module/namespace 'Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers' from compilation unit 'FSharp.Core' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'LeafExpressionConverter'`

At first I thought it was because the project was using the old Powerpack LINQ stuff, so I stripped that out. Then I thought maybe it had something to do with using Entity Framework 4.3 instead of 5.0, so I upgraded that. Same error. I'm still compiling to .NET 4.0, not 4.5... perhaps this is part of the cause?

I compared the `Doctypes.fsproj` XML with other projects in the same solution, and everything looks normal. The `FSharp.Core` reference is simply `<Reference Include="FSharp.Core" />`

This is a *very* large project, so creating a small reproducible version of this error may take me a while to figure out, and I'm wondering if anyone here has a quick answer.

Here's the MSBUILD output:

```
19> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:obj\Debug\DTC.Doctypes.dll -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\Doctypes.XML --optimize- --tailcalls- --resource:statutes_ebook_cover.jpg -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Doctypes\bin\Debug\CsvHelper.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Data\bin\Debug\DTC.Data.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Formats\bin\Debug\DTC.Formats.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Parser\bin\Debug\DTC.Parser.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\ReferenceParser\bin\Debug\DTC.ReferenceParser.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Shared\bin\Debug\DTC.Shared.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Solr\bin\Debug\DTC.Solr.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Utilities\bin\Debug\DTC.Utilities.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Doctypes\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\packages\HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.6\lib\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\packages\DotNetZip.1.9.1.8\lib\net20\Ionic.Zip.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\packages\LegislativeData.1.0.2773.180\lib\net40\LegislativeData.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\packages\LibrarianData.1.0.2773.6\lib\net40\Librarian.Data.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Lib\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Lib\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll" -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.4.5.11\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll -r:A:\svn\dtc\Publisher\Repository\bin\Debug\Repository.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Configuration.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Entity.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Numerics.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll" --target:library --warn:4 --warnaserror --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --validate-type-providers --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --highentropyva- "C:\Users\dfitch\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.fs" Helpers.fs Paths.fs FolioImport.fs Epub.fs Kindle.fs Ebooks.fs SharedLaw.fsi SharedLaw.fs SharedIndex.fs HistoryLinks.fs AdministrativeCodeHeaders.fs AdministrativeCode.fs AdministrativeCodeTOC.fs AdministrativeCodeIndex.fs SCRHeaders.fs Register.fs StatuteHeaders.fs Statutes.fs StatutesTOC.fs StatutesIndex.fs CrossReferences.fs SupremeCourtRules.fs Constitution.fs SessionTypes.fs CrDocs.fs EmergencyRules.fs OracleSession.fs LatsSession.fs TestSessionData.fs Session.fs Votes.fs SessionText.fs FiscalEstimates.fs LatsBulletinIndex.fs SharedBulletinIndex.fs AuthorIndex.fs SubjectIndex.fs JournalIndex.fs CrIndex.fs ActIndex.fs SectionsAffected.fs LCAmendmentMemos.fs LCActMemos.fs LCDocuments.fs RecordsOfCommitteeProceedings.fs VetoMessages.fs AssemblyInfo.fs Journals.fs Calendars.fs ProposalText.fs AmendmentText.fs EnrolledBillsText.fs RDAttachments.fs ActText.fs Budget.fs LegislativeRules.fs DraftingManual.fs AdminRulesManual.fs DraftingFiles.fs ExecutiveOrders.fs CapitolHeadlines.fs TownLawForms.fs FolioBillHist.fs FolioLaw.fs FolioSessionImport.fsi FolioSessionImport.fs FolioSession.fs FolioMisc.fs FolioIndexes.fs FolioCr.fs Wislaw.fs Help.fs Disclaimers.fs Dnotes.fs CCC.fs LCMemos.fs oag.fs AdministrativeCodeCites.fs StatutesRepealedRenumbered.fs LRBUserProcedures.fs LRBDraftingManual.fs 
19>FSC: error FS0193: The module/namespace 'Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers' from compilation unit 'FSharp.Core' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'LeafExpressionConverter'
19>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets(155,9): warning MSB5021: "Fsc" and its child processes are being terminated in order to cancel the build.
19>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets(155,9): error : Build was canceled.
```

Comment: Searching for `LeafExpressionConverter` led me to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323986.aspx).  It's a bit hidden, but the bottom of the page says *"F# Core Library Versions
Supported in: 4.0, Portable."*  Don't know if that means anything to you or not.  Also, the page is marked "Visual Studio 2012" only, which does suggest a dependency on .NET 4.5.

Comment: The project was on VS2010/F#2.0 (which was core version 4.0) before, and it was fine... I suspect one of the library dependencies on something in LINQ is interacting strangely with the `FSharp.Core` stuff. Next step is to try compiling against 4.5, but I'd rather not if I don't have to...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your MSBuild output shows a reference to...

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll`.

That's the F# 2.0 version of FSharp.Core. You need to reference the F# 3.0 version instead:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\3.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll`

Comment: Strange. When in VS2012, if I remove the FSharp.Core reference and add the 4.3.0.0 one from the "Extensions" section of the reference dialog, it adds the 4.0.0.0 version. If I browse to that path manually, it adds a `HintPath` to the project file and works correctly. Thanks for spotting that... wacky.